# Displaying all photos from all albums of a Facebook page

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following is my code which I am using to display images from Facebook fan page. The code works fine but the problem is that its not getting images from all photo albums. It's restricted to profile pictures album only. Kindly let me know how can I modify the following code so it displays images from all albums.

```
<?php
$facebook_album = file_get_contents(
            "http://graph.facebook.com/194458563914948/photos?limit=50");
$dataArr = json_decode($facebook_album, true);

foreach($dataArr['data'] as $d){    
    echo "<img src=\"".$d['source']."\"><br />";    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using Graph API:

#### Separated queries

1. Get all albums ID: `graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/albums`
2. For each album ID, get the pictures: `graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID?fields=photos.fields(source)`

#### One-liner

```
graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/albums?fields=photos.limit(100).fields(source)
```

### Using FQL:

#### Multi-query

```
{
"query1":"SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = PAGE_ID", 
"query2":"SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM #query1)"
}
```

#### One-liner

```
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid 
    IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=PAGE_ID)
```

Comment: okay, when i used this url `http://graph.facebook.com/194458563914948/albums?fields=photos` its gives the json data of all the images in my album but when i put this to my code , my code gave an error of `Notice: Undefined index: source` where as when i run this url `http://graph.facebook.com/194458563914948/photos?limit=50` it runs like a charm in my code, can you please indicate what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to get the source attribute of the photo. You need to additionally request this source field using `photos.fields(source)`. I also just found out that we can do that using a single query. Check out my answer update.

Comment: +1 Thanks for all your efforts, I noticed when i give albums id separately it shows me the images perfectly but when i give this url or the like then i got the error message `Notice: Undefined index: source` `http://graph.facebook.com/194458563914948/albums?fields=photos.limit(100).fields(source)` (Maybe that's not possible to display all the photos in one go from my code above), one last question is there a way to get images from url like `https://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME/photos_stream?ref=ts`

Comment: Being a different query, it doesn't return the same array... Therefore you won't access the information the same way. You should display your array `print_r($dataArr)` and try to understand how the data is stored. Compare both previous and new arrays, think a little and then, adapt your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks alot I found some way to resolve my problem, I am getting ids from all albums and then display images album wise I think its a good way of doing thing, its bit organized what's say?